# How do I select a specific number of rows from column B depending on if Column A is greater than 0 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, calculated-columns

I have a data matrix of random numbers in Matlab numbers ranging 0-9 (so two columns and ten rows). If the Column A row 3 is greater than 0, I want to create a new column starting from row 3 to give me 5 following numbers from row 3 of Column B.

Is there an easy way to do this in the command window in matlab?

Comment: 5 consecutive or any 5 ?

Comment: consecutive as described i comments below

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I'm interpreting the question correctly:

```
test = rand(10,2);
if test(3,1) > 0; new_column = test(3:7,2); end
```

```
% Setup
x = rand(10,1);
y = rand(10,1);
xx = logical(x);

z = 5;

% One-liner
w = zeros(sum((xx==1)),z); step = 1; for ii = 1:length(xx), if xx(ii) == 1, w(step,:) = y(ii:(ii+z-1)); step = step+1; end,end,
```

However, if xx == 1 at an index greater than (z+1) you're not going to get z observations and this will error out. You need to further clarify what you're looking to do.

Is there any particular reason why this has to be done in the command line?

Comment: Thanks. Basically i am typing directly into command window. I have created xx=logical(x); to create a binary 0 or 1 answer. Now I want to add a condition where i create a new variable e.g z=5. Now i want to create a third time series where in if xx is 1, then i take the equivelent (z) number of subsequent observation from time series y. Y  just like x consists of 10 rows. So if in x row 3 is 1 i want to create sereis w that will extract 5 rows of data from series y from row 3. Please help.

Comment: @Noob_1 see my edit. I'm not sure you've thought through your criteria properly.